# Change Angular router-outlet css depending on housed component?

Tags: css, angular, dom-manipulation, router-outlet

So I have a router-outlet that I'm using to switch between components on the side of another component. I want to be able to change the outlet width depending on the housed component. Currently I'm using a shared service to determine that:

```
<div class="service.widthType">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In between components, I'm changing the shared service properties to determine the class and thereby the width:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.widthType = "small" // Or "medium" or "large" depending on the component
}
```

Is this considered good practice or is there a better way to do this?

edit: correcting code

Comment: You need `this.service.widthType = "small"` in your component method and `[class]="service.widthType"` in your component markup.

Comment: How about letting the routed component's CSS determine its `max-width`?

Comment: Ah good point @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen. For got to add that. 
I am more or less changing the width, I'm just trying to figure out how to determine the inner component, from there I can change it's CSS. Is there an imbedded method or some service that does exactly that?

Comment: You can add additional data to the routes indicating the "size" (small, medium or large) and then subscribe to router events.